# facebook php SDK, publish_stream OAuthException: (#200)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this error has been bitten to death over here, and I read every single one to have better understanding of my problem.

But my issue is a bit different, and I wonder if anyone can give me good suggestion where to look.

I'm using wordpress + wordpress social login. This plugin authenticates user and stores name/age/email/fbID/fbProfilePic in the DB.

I've a little feature on my website where users registered through facebook can click and post message to the their wall.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
//IF user is registered via facebook, when he clicks INTERESTED message will appear on his/her wall to spread the news

  $user = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'Facebook',true);

    if ($user && $_GET['commentstab'] == 1 && !$_POST['delmycom']) {



      require ('Facebook/facebook.php');

      //Access details
      $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'XXX',
        'secret' => 'XXX'
        //'cookie' => true
      ));


          //try {
              $params = array(
                  'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
                  'name'          =>  "This is my title",
                  'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
                  'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
                  'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
                  'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png",
              );
              $post = $facebook->api("/$user/feed","POST",$params);

              echo "Your post was successfully posted to UID: $user";
          //} //try

          //catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          //    $result = $e->getResult();
          //} //catch


    } //master if
?>
```

I read in various topics that I need publish_stream permission from user to perform this action. But since I store user info separately in my own DB, how do I get this publish stream permission? Do I need to modify wordpress plugin to store some kind of access token? and utilize this token to post to wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you generate loginurl with publish_stream permission
2. if user is not logged in with permission, you have to make sure he does
3. redirect user to proper page

you can do it like this,

```
<?php
include_once("facebook.php"); 
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => APP_ID,
      'secret' => APP_SECRET,
      'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();



    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
      }
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>'publish_stream','redirect_uri'=>'example.com'));
      die('<script> top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'";</script>');
    }

    $params = array(
                  'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
                  'name'          =>  "This is my title",
                  'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
                  'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
                  'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
                  'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png",
              );
    $post = $facebook->api("/$user/feed","POST",$params); 
?>
```

Comment: I figured it out, modified the wp plugin to ask for publish_stream permission in the first place. Can you tell me what cookie true does?

Comment: when you are using Javascript sdk too, the server side can access the session.